# Using regex to find chars in a string and replace

Tags: java, android, regex

When returning a string value from an incoming request in my network based app, I have a string like this
`'post http://a.com\r\nHost: a.com\r\n'`

Issue is that the host is always changing so I need to replace it with my defined host. To accomplish that I tried using regex but am stuck trying to find the `'host:a.com'` chars in the string and replacing it with a defined valued.

I tried using this example [www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/search_replace_loop.shtml#.VUWvt541jqB](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/search_replace_loop.shtml#.VUWvt541jqB) changing the pattern compile to :`([\\d]+)` but it still remains unchanged.

My goal is to replace given chars in a string with a defined value and returning the new string with the defined value.
Any pointers?

**EDIT**:
Sample of a typical incoming request:
`Post http://example.com\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n`

Another incoming request might take this form:
`GET http://example2.net\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: example2.net\r\n`

I want to replace it to this forms
`Post http://example.com\r\nHost: mycustomhostvalue.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n`

`GET http://example2.net\r\nContent-Length: 2\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: mycustomhostvalue.com\r\n`

Comment: Did you try one of `myStr.replace("someString", "someOther");` or `replaceAll("someRegex", "someString");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex to replace it, like this:

```
content = content.replaceAll("Host:\\s*(\\w)*\\.\\w*", "Host: newhost.com")
```

This will replace anything after `Host:` with `newHost.com`.

Note: as per comment by cfqueryparam, you may want to usea regex like this to cover `.co.uk` and such:

```
Host:\\s*.*?(?=\\\\r\\\\n)
```

Comment: I usually don't know the host values as the are different with each incoming request.  So doing  replace('  I think won't work

Comment: @codeFreak, If you want to do it with regex, you have to know what you want to replace. Maybe you could show some ample of your input data and haw you want to get the hostnames from it.

Comment: Have added sample inputs in my original post @JonasCz

Comment: I would suggest a regex more like this `Host:\\s*.*?(?=\\\\r\\\\n)` to cover multiple domains like `.co.uk` if they should arise. Sure, other regexes could work too, but this is a pretty simple solution.

Comment: @cfqueryparam, Thanks !  I added it to answer, I hope thats okay.

Comment: @JonasCz Indeed it is. That's why I commented rather than answered.